# Json Android problem

Tags: android, json

I am tring to get news from json. Averything works clear but the question is, my listview work so slow and force close or wait buttons appears. Is it because it dynamicly gets the information. 
How should i get the informations in a array and get the news from there. I only want to refresh when refresh button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Move data loading to the separate thread(not UI one) and execute some callback when loading completes(to actually update your listview)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the async task for any data transfer over the network.See the detail below:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Hope this helps!